# how to hide cute report print dialog in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have an problem, I am making an invoice management application with Qt and Cute Report library. everything is working but, when I click on print button there is an print dialog that I don't want, how can I hide that and continue printing.

dialog that I highlighted in this image:

[image]

I have tried to set printer property ShowDialog to false but no luck.

I tried that:

```
reportCore->printer("printer")->setProperty("showDialog", "false");
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: At the end of the day it is an OS service that does printing on Windows. You can request no dialog all you want, but unless there is a working default driver it has no choice but to present a dialog.